# Google Drive API: How to identify the Parent (folder) of a file object returned from a $service->change->getChanges() list

Tags: php, google-drive-api, listchanged

I am trying to obtain the parent folder for a file object in a Google Drive API php script.

The relevant code:

```
$idChangeHistory = [] ;
do {
    $response = $service->changes->listChanges($nextPageToken, [ 'spaces' => 'drive' ] ) ;
    if ( (! is_null($response->newStartPageToken))) {
        $savedStartPageToken = $response->newStartPageToken ;
        $historyRow['nextStartPageToken'] = $savedStartPageToken ;
        }

    // I collect the change IDs because there may be multiple changes per file.
    // We don't care - we only want the final one.  But we'll count the revisions.
    foreach ($response->changes as $change) {
        $googleId = $change->fileId ;
        if (array_key_exists($googleId, $idChangeHistory))
            $idChangeHistory[$googleId]['count']++ ;
        else
            $idChangeHistory[$googleId] = [ 'count' => 1 ] ;
        }
    $nextPageToken = $response->nextPageToken ;
    } while ($nextPageToken) ;

foreach ($idChangeHistory as $googleId => $elements) {
    $fileObj = $service->files->get($googleId) ;
    $mimeType = $fileObj->getMimeType() ;
    $name = $fileObj->getName() ;
    $parents = $fileObj->getParents() ; // This comes up null ??????
    $size = $fileObj->getSize() ;
    $trashed = $fileObj->getTrashed() ;
    $createdTime = $fileObj->getCreatedTime() ;
    $modifiedTime = $fileObj->getModifiedTime() ;
    // Somehow we need to get Folder name and parentId.
    // (We can get the parent ID from DB if we can obtain folder name)
    // (unless folder is new?)
    $something = processEntry($fileObj, $folderName, $countsArray, $parentId) ;
    }
```

...but what I'm finding is that most of these fields don't actually populate with values - they get set to null.  In particular, **$obj->getParentd()** returns null, where I expected an array. With the above code, only $mimeType and $name get populated.  All the others have value = null.

I know that $service->files->listFiles() allows for a "fields" parameter, and (for the most part) only those fields mentioned there are actually populated.  For example:

```
$result = $service->files->listFiles(
        [ 'fields' => 'files(id,name,mimeType,fileExtension,size,parents,createdTime,modifiedTime,trashed),nextPageToken'
        , 'q' => sprintf('"%s" in parents', $myGoogleId)
          ] ;
```

But it appears that this capability is not available with $service->files->get($id).

How do I get the file object populated, or alternatively get the parent ID for a file object retrieved in this manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$fileObj = $service->files->get($googleId) ;
```

#### To:

```
$fileObj = $service->files->get($googleId, ["fields" => "*"]);
```

or,

```
$fileObj = $service->files->get($googleId, ["fields" => "mimeType,size,name,parents,trashed,createdTime,modifiedTime"]);
```

- In the current stage, it seems that Drive API v3 doesn't return all file metadata as the default response value. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, it is required to use `fields`. By this modification, `parents` is returned.

#### References:

- [Method: files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get)
- [Return specific fields for a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/fields-parameter)
- [REST Resource: files of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files)

Comment: Brilliant!!!!   Is there documentation on this?  In both this case and the one I listed in the question ($service->files->listFiles() I have this code _solely_because_ someone has said 'do it this way' (in so many words).  THANK YOU so much for this invaluable answer.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for replying. About `Is there documentation on this?`, how about this official document? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/fields-parameter) And, in the case of fields of file metadata with Drive API v3, how about this official document? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files) I check the detailed file metadata from this page. I added these references in my answer. If those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I apologize, you're right of course.  Those were right in front of me and I somehow missed them. Excellent work, much appreciated.  Sorry I missed that on the first go-round.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your question was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If my answer was not useful, I have to apologize.

Comment: yes, you have resolved the issue.  Mondai ga awaremashita (I think I remember that correctly).  Problem no longer exists. Thank you so much for your help.  I have accepted your answer and my script is executing beautifully.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I thought I had already accepted this answer.  My poor eyes can usually detect the bright checkmark, but on the old monitor I was using I missed it.  Anyway.... you got me going right away.  No need to reply, but I thank you again.